# How can I click a src img by its Attribute Id using xpath?

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

Hey guys iam fairly new to Java and I was wondering how I could go about clicking on an HTML elements image source by its related attribute. So i basically want to click on the elements source image that contains the related attribute id such as DATA-P1="1:204|13:10" as shown in the element img tag below:

```
<img style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; width: 8px; height: 8px; left: 825px; top: 1723px; display: block;" src="https://media.info/sy.png" **DATA-P1**="1:204|13:10" data-pl="2" xpath="1" />
```

I know I'm probably way off with detail, but this is what I have so far and it doesn't seem to work for me.

ideal Xpath value:

```
//*[@id="DATA-P1"]/img@src="https://media.info/sy.png[1:204|13:10]
```

However The following works to locate the related image but I would like to click on the image based off searching by the data-p1 value.

working Xpath value:

```
//*[@id="surface"]/img[164]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried: `//img[@DATA-P1 = '1:204|13:10']`?

Comment: @KunLun you are the man!! Thank you lots dude!!